# How to exclude rows with similar columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

There is a table:

```
| date        | action | issue_id |
| 2020-12-14  | close  | 1        |
| 2020-12-15  | close  | 1        |
| 2020-12-16  | close  | 1        |
| 2020-12-14  | close  | 2        |
```

How can I select only the last row with an action == close for each issue_id in one query?

```sql
SELECT action, issue_id
FROM table
WHERE action = 'close'
AND ???
```

Comment: All columns `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter no, they might be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these three columns only, aggregation is sufficient:

```
select issue_id, max(date) as date
from mytable 
where action = 'close'
group by issue_id
```

If you have more columns that you need to display, then use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (issue_id) t.*
from mytable t
where action = 'close'
order by issue_id, date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct on` :

```
select distinct on (issue_id) t.*
from table t
where action = 'close'
order by issue_id, date desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... columns might be null.

So be sure to use `DESC NULLS LAST` to avoid surprising results:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (issue_id) *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  action = 'close'
ORDER  BY issue_id, date DESC NULLS LAST;
```

And you may want to append another unique expression (like `tbl_id`) to the `ORDER BY` list to break ties among equal dates if that can happen. Else you get an arbitrary pick that can change with every execution.

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)